# Generating connected rooms with corridors using Minimum Spanning Tree in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graph, game-development, procedural-generation

I've been working on a top-down game that involves procedurally generating levels. So far, I've managed to create individual rooms based on a seed, but now I'm facing a challenge when trying to connect these rooms together using corridors. Instead of achieving a single connected tree-like structure, I'm ending up with multiple disconnected clusters of rooms.

To address this, I've been attempting to use a Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm along with Kruskal's algorithm to connect the rooms with corridors. However, I've hit a roadblock: the corridors are starting from the center of the rooms, whereas I want them to start from the walls.

In pursuit of a solution, I've developed the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LevelGenerator1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject floorPrefab;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;
    public GameObject corridorPrefab;
    public int mapWidth = 100;
    public int mapHeight = 100;
    public int roomSizeMin = 5;
    public int roomSizeMax = 15;
    public int seed = 12345;

    private Transform mapHolder;
    private bool[,] usedTiles;

    private List<Vector2Int> rooms = new List<Vector2Int>();

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateLevel();
    }

    void GenerateLevel()
    {
        mapHolder = new GameObject("Generated Map").transform;
        usedTiles = new bool[mapWidth, mapHeight];

        Random.InitState(seed);

        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
            {
                if (!usedTiles[x, y])
                {
                    // Generate rooms
                    if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) > 0.8f)
                    {
                        int roomWidth = Random.Range(roomSizeMin, roomSizeMax);
                        int roomHeight = Random.Range(roomSizeMin, roomSizeMax);

                        int startX = x - roomWidth / 2;
                        int startY = y - roomHeight / 2;

                        if (IsSpaceAvailable(startX, startY, roomWidth, roomHeight))
                        {
                            GenerateRoom(startX, startY, roomWidth, roomHeight);
                            rooms.Add(new Vector2Int(startX + roomWidth / 2, startY + roomHeight / 2));
                            MarkTilesUsed(startX, startY, roomWidth, roomHeight);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ConnectRooms();
    }

    bool IsSpaceAvailable(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        for (int i = x; i < x + width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < y + height; j++)
            {
                if (i < 0 || i >= mapWidth || j < 0 || j >= mapHeight || usedTiles[i, j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void MarkTilesUsed(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        for (int i = x; i < x + width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < y + height; j++)
            {
                usedTiles[i, j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void GenerateRoom(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        for (int i = x; i < x + width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y; j < y + height; j++)
            {
                Vector3 tilePosition = new Vector3(i, j, 0);

                if (i == x || i == x + width - 1 || j == y || j == y + height - 1)
                {
                    GameObject wallTile = Instantiate(wallPrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    wallTile.transform.parent = mapHolder;
                }
                else
                {
                    GameObject floorTile = Instantiate(floorPrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    floorTile.transform.parent = mapHolder;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void ConnectRooms()
    {
        List<Edge> edges = new List<Edge>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < rooms.Count; j++)
            {
                Vector2Int roomA = rooms[i];
                Vector2Int roomB = rooms[j];
                float distance = Vector2Int.Distance(roomA, roomB);
                edges.Add(new Edge(i, j, distance));
            }
        }

        edges.Sort((a, b) => a.distance.CompareTo(b.distance));

        List<int> takenIndices = new List<int>();
        List<int> connectedIndices = new List<int>();

        foreach (Edge edge in edges)
        {
            if (!takenIndices.Contains(edge.from) || !takenIndices.Contains(edge.to))
            {
                connectedIndices.Add(edge.from);
                connectedIndices.Add(edge.to);
                takenIndices.Add(edge.from);
                takenIndices.Add(edge.to);

                Vector2Int roomA = rooms[edge.from];
                Vector2Int roomB = rooms[edge.to];

                GenerateCorridor(roomA, roomB);
            }
        }
    }

    void GenerateCorridor(Vector2Int pointA, Vector2Int pointB)
    {
        Vector2Int start = pointA;
        Vector2Int end = pointB;

        if (start.x > end.x)
        {
            Vector2Int temp = start;
            start = end;
            end = temp;
        }

        int corridorWidth = Mathf.Abs(end.x - start.x) + 1;
        int corridorHeight = Mathf.Abs(end.y - start.y) + 1;

        int corridorX = start.x;
        int corridorY = start.y;

        for (int i = 0; i < corridorWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < corridorHeight; j++)
            {
                Vector3 tilePosition = new Vector3(corridorX + i, corridorY + j, 0);
                GameObject corridorTile = Instantiate(corridorPrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.identity);
                corridorTile.transform.parent = mapHolder;
            }
        }
    }

    struct Edge
    {
        public int from;
        public int to;
        public float distance;

        public Edge(int from, int to, float distance)
        {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.distance = distance;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, Instead of achieving a single connected tree-like structure, I'm ending up with multiple disconnected clusters of rooms. The corridors are starting from the center of the rooms, whereas I want them to start from the walls. Additionally, the corridors I've managed to generate have varying widths and they sometimes overlap with the floor of the rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

I generated this image by

**- Randomly Locating the rooms**

I followed your scheme as much as possible, except I store the room locations using the top left corner co-ordinates.  ( The room centers are tricky because you have to divide by two and the result depends on what happens when an odd integer is divided by two.  Your scheme would work better if you used floats rather than integers, but using integer top-left keeps things simple )

**- Calculating the MST**

I followed your suggestion of calculating the minimum spanning tree.  Works well!  ( Maybe you have a bug in your MST calculation? )  For this, I used the well tested code in my graph theory library ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder )

**- Calculating corridor end points**

We want , I think, the corridors to go between the middle of adjacent room boundaries of two rooms linked by the MST.  Some tricky coding required here to get perfect results.  Most important trick is to root the MST at the room at the top right, so that the rooms are only linked from left to right and top to bottom.  Here is the code

```
void cLevelGenerator1::generateCorridor(
    cRoom &rooma, cRoom &roomb)
{
    if (rooma.y+rooma.h-1 < roomb.y)
    {
        // from bottom middle to left middle
        corridors.emplace_back(
            rooma.x + rooma.w / 2, rooma.y + rooma.h - 1,
            roomb.x + roomb.w / 2, roomb.y);
    }
    else if ( 
     rooma.x+rooma.w - 1 < roomb.x )
    {
        //from right middle to left middle
        corridors.emplace_back(
            rooma.x+rooma.w-1, rooma.y+rooma.h/2,
            roomb.x,roomb.y+roomb.h/2 );
    }
    else
    {
        // from top middle to bottom middle
        corridors.emplace_back(
            rooma.x+rooma.w/2,rooma.y,
            roomb.x+roomb.w/2,roomb.y+roomb.h-1 );
    }
}
```

The complete C++ code for the application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/corridors

( Sorry, I know you want c# code.  However, I found porting your c# code to C++ straight forward, so you can probably port it back again )